# Setting Static style in a flowdocument so that only Style=(static somestyle} is saved with the document

Tags: .net, styles, flowdocument

I am successfully assigning a named style to a flowdocument element's style property in code.

```
   wStyle = this.FindResource(MyStyleName) as Style;
   wParagraph.Style = wStyle;
```

But when the document is saved instead of getting something like Style="{StaticResource MyStyleName}" I get a vast hierarchy of property setters. The document is now 90% redundant style information.

Problem: How do I set the style to reference a named style and not copy it.

I am now stumped. I have considered saving the style name in the Tag property and then updating the document's xaml  to remove and replace the style information. I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed my own advice and stored the named style in the Tag attribute.

When I save the document I pass it through a filter which removes the Paragraph.Style element and replaces it with a Style attribute of the form Style="{DynamicResource SomeStyleName}". Note that DynamicResource is required as the document will not parse when it is loaded.

In my case only paragraphs have named styles. The code for the filter is as follows:

```
    private string ReplaceStyleInfo(string pTopicContent)
    {
        // RichtextBox inlines named styles (H1 etc.) on paragraphs as huge hierarchies of setters - so drop all stlye info and set to the Form Style="{StaticResource stylename}"
        // The named style is held in the Tag property.
        XDocument wXDocument = XDocument.Parse(pTopicContent);

        var wParagraphs = from p in wXDocument.Root.Elements()
                          where p.Name.LocalName == "Paragraph"
                          select p;

        foreach (XElement wParagraph in wParagraphs)
        {
            if (wParagraph.Attribute("Tag") != null)
            {
                var wStyleName = wParagraph.Attribute("Tag").Value;
                XAttribute  wStyleAttribute = wParagraph.Attribute("Style");
                if (wStyleAttribute == null)
                {
                    wParagraph.Add(new XAttribute("Style", "{DynamicResource " + wStyleName + "}"));
                }
                else
                {
                    wStyleAttribute.Value = "{DynamicResource " + wStyleName + "}";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                 XAttribute  wStyleAttribute = wParagraph.Attribute("Style");
                 if (wStyleAttribute != null)
                 {
                     wStyleAttribute.Remove();
                 }
            }
            var wParagraphStyle = from p in wParagraph.Elements()
                                  where p.Name.LocalName == "Paragraph.Style"
                                  select p;
            wParagraphStyle.Remove();

        }
        return wXDocument.ToString();
    }
```

This works nicely and reduces the saved documents by about 80%.

At run time the named styles are resolved by a ResourceDictionary provided to the FlowDocumentScrollViewer (for viewing) and RichTextBoox (for editing).